# Aggregation vs composition in Python

Tags: python, object, associations, aggregation, composition

Regardless of how I create objects (composition or aggregation), I still see the same instantiated object count in memory, i.e. only one ContainerClass object assigned to the 'container' variable. I'm looking at the objects in memory using dir() or locals(). **What I wanted to see was how objects in the case of aggregation can outlast the container object if its deleted.** However, if only one object is created in each case, then how can I see aggregation vs composition in action?

**Composition:**

```
class ContainerClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.content = ContentClass()

class ContentClass:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

container = ContainerClass()
```

**Aggregation:**

```
class ContainerClass:
    def __init__(self, content):
        self.content = content

class ContentClass:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

container = ContainerClass(ContentClass())
```

My other related question is, if an object is not assigned to a variable upon instantiation, does it not count as an object for the purposes of dir() or locals()? Why do these functions only show objects in memory that have been assigned to a variable?

Comment: What makes you think `dir` shows *any* objects?

Comment: Well, dir() does show 'container', I guess as a property/attribute available globally.

Comment: `dir` is documented as returing *names*, not objects. (Well, ok, names appear to be string objects, but I'm not even sure that's not just an implementation detail, plus in any case that doesn't seem to be the kind of "objects" you mean).